# 'Aggregate and compress CSS files' and 'Aggregate JavaScript files' don't work

Tags: 7, css-js-aggregation

Recently selecting *Aggregate and compress CSS files* or *Aggregate JavaScript files* in the Performance page stopped working on a Drupal 7 site: When they are selected, the CSS/JavaScript file won't load.

I have cloned the site on another server and the problem doesn't occur there. The PHP version and the Drupal version (7.89) is the same.

How can I debug what is going on here?

**Edit: Additional info**

As I mentioned in the comments, the aggregated CSS files are not viewable in the browser. However, If I change the filename to e.g. test.css, it then *is* viewable.

**Further:**

Each aggregate file has a corresponding .gz of the same name. When I delete this the .css file is then viewable via the browser. So it looks like the issue has something to with these .gz files.

Comment: Typically this is due to a folder permission issue. Make sure the `/sites/default/files` folder has the correct folder owner and group besides having the appropriate `chmod 755` permissions.

Comment: Unfortunately in this case the permissions are correct.

Comment: What does "When they are selected, the CSS/JavaScript file won't load" actually mean? Are the files not generated on disk, or not referenced properly in the HTML?

Comment: @cilefen E.g There are references to aggregated CSS within the HTML. When I open these via FTP they have data within them, but I try and view them in the browser via the site's HTML they are apparently empty.

Comment: How does the web server's configuration differ between the working site's and broken site's?

Comment: Also: they are empty? Is the HTTP response a 200 code?

Comment: @cilefen both Apache, both running PHP 7.4. The empty pages have a 200 response.

Comment: Are the web server's configurations identical?

Comment: @cilefen probably not. The working one is a shared server, the non-working one is a VPS with the same company. I'm not sure how to find detailed info re: the configurations (aside from asking them of course).

Comment: It seems like new aggregate CSS files are not created when there's a change and aggregation is then chosen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it turns out that mod_headers wasn't enabled on my server, which therefore meant that the *'# Rules to correctly serve gzip compressed CSS and JS files'* section within .htaccess didn't work.

It used to be fine, so it looks like the hosting company changed the Apache config recently